# Call to undefined method Session::has() in Laravel 5 + Codeception functional testing

Tags: php, session, laravel-5, codeception, php-5.6

I was running some functional tests in Laravel 5 with Codeception.

Below is a sample test

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\WithoutMiddleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseTransactions;

class HomePageTestCest
{
    use WithoutMiddleware;

    public function _before(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        //some setup to run
    }

    public function _after(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
    }

    // tests
    public function tryToTest(FunctionalTester $I)
    {
        $I->wantToTest('If i can go to home page without errors');
        $I->amOnPage('/');
        $I->canSee('WELCOME TO HOMEPAGE');
    }
}
```

But i am getting below error while running the test:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Session::has() in /var/www/laravel5/storage/framework/views/e7953b3ce9b90e51d4cfdb279790953bbe25dc9a.php on line 225
```

And in line 225 i have:

```
<?php if(Session::has('someKey')): ?>
  //some html code
<?php endif; ?>
```

I think the problem is with session driver. I also tried to implement [this](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6138) but nothing changed.

Hope will get some help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write the full namespace as: `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::has('something')`

Comment: Is it necessary to write full namespace specially for functional testing??

Comment: @hamedmehryar your solution worked, but can you explain why i have to define whole namespace??

Comment: Maybe `Session` is not listed in the `aliases` array in `app.php` config file.

Comment: Nope, i checked and its listed. Same happened for Config::get() also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **LARAVEL 5.2** they also create the session class like helper

where in you can make use of it like this

```
session()->has('key')
```

See [DOCUMENTATION SESSION](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session)

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

// import session class using alias
use Session;

class SampleController exntends Controller {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function index() {
        // print session values
        var_dump(Session::all());
    }

}
```

Comment: Hey, sorry i totally over looked your solution somehow. Your solution also works. But do you know the reason, why Session:: not working? thnx in advance.

Comment: I believe that the alias classes are automatically required unlike in the laravel 4. Here is a link that discuss your problem. If you want to make use of facades aliases import the class by using the use Session; then you can  already make use of Session::has('key'). I update my answer so you can follow what i mean

Comment: Hey thnx for replying back. Yes i tried that already but didnt work. Only thing that works for testing is when i use the full path like Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session which is really wired, like i described in my answer below. I was looking for a reason or most precisely an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to **hamedmehryar** for the solution. I dont know why but for some reason i have to define whole namespace for the facades, even they are already defined in 'aliases' inside config/app.php. For example:

```
Session::has()
```

should be like

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::has()
```

I explained it here so if anyone face this problem will be able to solve it from here.

Answer (score 0):

Do not forget

`use Illuminate\Http\Request;`.

AND use session like this

`$request->session()->has('key');`